# How to use origins tag vs. history-of tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not clear on when to use the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag and/or the [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) tag. It seems to me that about 70% of the questions tagged [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) are asking about origins and would fall under the definition of the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag. On the other hand, many of the questions tagged [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) are about the history of the genre. (According to the *definition* of the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag I'd expect *all* of the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) questions to be historical.)

Please explain (preferably with an example for each case) what questions should be tagged [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) rather than [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins), what questions should be tagged [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) rather than [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), and what questions (if any) should get both of those tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Tag Wikis, [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) is "a tag for questions that seek to identify the first appearances of specific things in the world of scifi and fantasy, like characters, items, themes, and/or theories."

[history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) is for "Questions about the history of the genre".

So, in theory, [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) seems like a clear subset of [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).  I can't think of a single example where [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) would be appropriate where it would also not be appropriate to have [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).

As you pointed out, their use has been pretty inconsistent. I see quite a few "first appearance" questions that lack [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins), but include [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), and vice versa.

In my opinion, we don't need both tags, and in fact, having both is causing enough confusion in their use to hinder any benefit from either of them.

I would propose merging them, and having [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) as the master.  If we make that change, we should also update the tag wiki for [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of): "This tag is for questions about the history of the world of scifi and fantasy, including, but not limited to, identification of the first appearances of specific things, like characters, items, themes, tropes, and/or theories" (suggestions are welcome for further improving the tag wiki).

Comment: Good answer. A few nitpicky suggestions and questions about the proposed wording. (1) Change "like" to "such as". (2) Maybe change "and/or" to "and" or "or"? (3) Not sure what "world" means in "history of the world of scifi and fantasy"; would the meaning be any different if it were "history of the genre(s) of scifi and fantasy" or just "history of scifi and fantasy"? (4) Is the unhyphenated "scifi" the preferred spelling here, or does it vary randomly between "scifi" and "sci-fi"? I see that there are tags named [tag:hard-sci-fi] and [tag:soft-sci-fi].

Comment: 1) sounds good. 2) I tend to prefer and/or, as it openseither ppossibility , but I'm not dead-set on it. 3) I don't particularly like world either. I like genre better.  4) I'm honestly not sure. I suspect it's random. I like "scifi", but the convention is is usually to hyphenate tags, so that might be contributing.

Comment: +1 . Frankly, I was assuming origins (without reading the Wiki) was about origin stories of SFF characters, so this tag is DOUBLY misleading.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] - see [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/can-we-merge-the-history-of-tag-and-the-origins-tag).