# Can we merge the 'history-of' tag AND the 'origins' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

## Update

Thank you community members; this has been resolved now :D

If a mod could mark this as [status-closed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-closed) that would be great thanks!

---

So, I was doing some editing the other day and I've come to form the opinion that [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) and [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) really should become synonyms.  This was previously discussed [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-to-use-origins-tag-vs-history-of-tag), but I don't think anything came from it.  So I'm renewing the push.

Why should these be synonyms?  Well, first take a look at the answer to the aforementioned question.

Also take a look at the usage guides for the two tags:

[history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of):

> Use this tag for questions about the history of the genre: **the origin and evolution of ideas** in speculative fiction.

[origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins):

> a tag for questions that seek to identify **the first appearances of specific things** in the world of scifi and fantasy, like characters, items, themes, and/or theories.

So, I would propose that [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) should become a synonym of [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins)

Comment: Voting on this can be done [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/history-of/synonyms), for anyone with a total answer score of >=5 in the tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I propose a slight variant of your suggestion: that

### [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) should become a synonym of [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).

As mentioned in the accepted answer to the previous question you mentioned, [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) is a subset of [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), and there are questions covered by the latter but not the former (e.g. about the *development* of an idea in SFF rather than its *origin*).

Comment: I like your thinking