# Synonymise [influences] and [inspiration] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [influences](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/influences) (23 questions) and [inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration) (26 questions) both seem to have roughly the same meaning: they're both for questions about where an SF/F author's ideas came from, what influenced or inspired them to write the things they did. Examples:

- [Is James T. Kirk known to be based on Horatio Hornblower?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48083/is-james-t-kirk-known-to-be-based-on-horatio-hornblower) [influences](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/influences)
- [Was the Hulk based on Jekyll/Hyde?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108260/was-the-hulk-based-on-jekyll-hyde) [inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration)
- [Erebor's architectural influences?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86553/erebors-architectural-influences) [influences](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/influences)
- [Who are the architects of the buildings on which these fictional buildings were based?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99814/who-are-the-architects-on-whose-buildings-the-buildings-were-based) [inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration)

### Shall we synonymise and merge these tags?

They also bear some similarity to the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag ([now synonymised](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/can-we-merge-the-history-of-tag-and-the-origins-tag) with the [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) tag), but I think the latter is different enough not to be synonymised: it's more about the **history of the genre as a whole**, e.g. "where did X first appear in science fiction literature?", whereas the [influences](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/influences)/[inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration) tags are more about the **history of a specific idea**, e.g. "where did author X get this idea?" (Admittedly the tag wikis should be edited to make this clear *[hint hint]* ...)

---

**Note:** PLEASE DO NOT start editing the tags on these questions manually before a consensus is reached here. The community has [expressed their disapproval](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9207/when-should-we-do-another-tag-cleanup) of multiple tag edits cluttering up the front page, and it's entirely unnecessary in this case: if we do agree to merge these tags, we can do the retagging automatically without bumping any questions at all.

Comment: Can't we just suggest synonyms as part of a privilege? Or does it have to go through meta?

Comment: @CreationEdge Anyone with more than 2500 rep and a score of more than 5 in the tag can suggest a synonym for others to vote on, but nobody else will notice it on [this page tucked away secretly](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/inspiration/synonyms) unless they advertise it on meta. Also, there's no way for a mod to do that without pushing the synonym straight through. Meta is the only place I've got to *suggest* a synonym and let others have a say.

Comment: This says completed, but why does influences show only 2 questions and inspiration shows 60? Shouldn't they be the same now?

Comment: @CreationEdge See SQB's answer. I merged the two tags without synonymising (so all the questions that *were* tagged with [tag:influences] are now tagged with [tag:inspiration]), and then SQB made a *new* [tag:influences] tag with a different meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, synonymize them.

There is, as you said, almost zero difference between them - they're just two different words.

[inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration) should be the one that goes, as it seems to have a slightly smaller scope than [influences](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/influences).

Comment: Which one should remain, and which one should be mapped to it?

Comment: @randal'thor edited.

Comment: @CreationEdge This was already resolved over a year ago. We still have both tags, but now they have clearly separate meanings and usages, as reflected in the tag wikis.

Answer (score 0):

We are *now* using [inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration) for questions about where authors got *their inspiration*, while using [influences](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/influences) on questions about the real world being *influenced by* SF&F works.

An example of the latter would be the waterbed that couldn't be patented because Heinlein had already described it in *Double Star*.

This change took place after the initial versions of the tags were merged.

Comment: That's certainly a valid idea, but it's not how the tags are used at the moment. If we're going to do this, we'd have to merge [tag:influences] with [tag:inspiration] (without synonymising) and *then* start using the [tag:influences] tag with its new meaning.

Comment: I just merged [tag:influences] with [tag:inspiration], without synonymising. Feel free to start reinventing the [tag:influences] tag with a different meaning.

Comment: @randal'thor Thank you.

Comment: @randal'thor see the new [tag:influences] tag.

Comment: Nice! Here's a couple more questions that could (possibly - see what you think) be given that tag: [one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99837/have-any-speculative-answers-from-this-site-been-used-in-any-subsequent-official), [two](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95971/which-2015-technologies-were-correctly-predicted-by-back-to-the-future-ii).

Comment: @randal'thor First one, [tag:inspiration] is okay, since the question is about _inspiration_ for works of SF&F. Second one, possibly.