# Are questions about the influence of SF works on later non-SF works on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Suppose work A is clear science fiction or fantasy, and work B is not.  Would it be on topic to ask about whether an on-topic aspect of A influenced a part of B?  For example, would it be on topic to ask whether
*The Karate Kid* (the Ralph Macchio movie) was named after the Karate Kid (the *Legion of the Superheroes* character)?

Comment: My instinct is that unless there's an obvious SFF connection between the two works, it wouldn't be in-topic to ask about a non-SFF property here. Go ask on Movies if it's a movie and Literature if it's a book

Comment: @Valorum I believe that's the SvG argument.

Answer (score 4):

**That's what the [influences](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/influences) tag is supposed to be for.**

See for example [What is the first mention of Star Wars in a hit song?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150736/31394) and [Did "The World Set Free" inspire the creation of nuclear weapons?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95219/31394) These seem to be exactly what you're talking about: questions about the influence of an SF/F work on the world outside of SF/F.

See also the previous meta [Synonymise [influences] and [inspiration] tags?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9226/31394) - especially SQB's answer.

In short: if work A is on-topic, then asking about possible connections between A and B should be on-topic. It might be wise, though, to phrase the question very much from A's point of view: instead of "*was B inspired by A?*", ask "*did A inspire B?*" People on this site are more likely to know about A than B, if A is on-topic but B isn't.