# Why can't I add the Origins tag to my question?

Tags: bug, tags

Why can't I add the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag to my question? Is it because I already used an edit to add [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of)?

[Is Tomboy of Sterling Comics, from 1954, the first independent comicbook superheroine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264285/is-tomboy-of-sterling-comics-from-1954-the-first-independent-comicbook-superhe)

Comment: There's also the fact that this is the incorrect tag. You're not interested in the origin of this character.

Comment: @Valorum - When I mouse over Origins, it still says what it said 5 years ago, about "First Appearances" of and I'm looking for the first comicbook independent superheroine, no? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/can-we-merge-the-history-of-tag-and-the-origins-tag

Answer (score 10):

The tag [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) is a *synonym* for [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).  So if you tag a question with [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) it will be automatically converted to [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).

If you view the page for  [questions tagged history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/history-of) and click on the [synonyms link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/history-of/synonyms) it tells you that "origins" is a synonym.